# Dynamic content, shows a 1 on each request

Tags: php

With my function what I have written I try thereby 2 things.

The links should be called like this `http://localhost/?login=Bla`, Now it is like this `http://localhost/login,php?login` "Bla

Next I would have asked, in my function a 1 is given after each call. I just can't figure out where this comes from, I've been sitting on this problem for a long time.

[Output with the 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTs1.png)

This is the code with which I can call the pages

```
function Seite($pagename, $lay){

    function Seite($pagename, $lay){

    $path = "$lay/$pagename.php";
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        openSeite($path);
    } 
}

function openSeite($pageurl){

    $fc = require($pageurl);
    echo $fc;
}
function echopage($slug, $fade){
    // $slug = ?SLUG=Seite
    // $fade = Ordner des Layout
    $page = isset($_GET["$slug"]) ? $_GET["$slug"] : "error";
    $contente = seite($page, "$fade");
    echo $contente;
}
```

I call the content on the index.php with

```
<? echopage("login", "admin/layout"); ?>
```

Comment: Function in a Fuction?? Might be worth fixing that first

Comment: I'm still working on making a class out of it.

Comment: A `require` will return `TRUE` if successful and will error if unsuccessful! So echoing the resuolt of a `require()` has no real use

Comment: The `1` is probably the result of outputting TRUE

Comment: what's the best way to fix this? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Dont do this `echo $fc;`

Comment: Uh so simple but still not figured out Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_GET["$slug"])` returns a 1 because it is set (true), write a traditional conditional with the echo inside the if statement.

***Better Yet** assign your output to a variable and concatenate the values accordingly.

```
$output = NULL;
if(isset($_GET["$slug"]){ 
    $contente = seite($page, "$fade");
    $output .= $contente;
}else{
    //handle error
}
```

HTML:

```
<?=$output?><!--Output your displayed text held in the variable-->
```

ISSUE:

```
$page = isset($_GET["$slug"]) ? $_GET["$slug"] : "error";
```

You are essentially returning the set value, which is `1` also `true`.

From php manual for value: *Returns TRUE if var exists and has any value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.*

You can test this by simply writing out a line of code `echo isset($var);` and checking the test php page. Then try defining a variable and doing the same thing. `$var = "this is set";` then `echo isset($var);`, you will get a 1.

Comment: I think I blacked out, with my variable $page